# In rails, given the account and the password, how to abtain the MSN contact list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, given the account and the password, how to abtain the MSN contact list?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is use an MSN API to retrieve the contact list.  I've never down it in ruby, but you can give this a try: http://code.google.com/p/rubymsn/.  It can be used to write a full fledged, ruby based, msn client, but they do have an API to retrieve the contact lists.